# How can I check if I have been passed NA rather than a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a routine that accepts a value. This value must be dataframe or NA, but the user can pass pretty much anything and I want to check.

the problem is that if I do is.na() on the passed value, I get TRUE or FALSE, but if that passed value is a data.frame I get a matrix. I want a TRUE or FALSE (false, in this case, as a data frame is not a NA). How do I do so?

Comment: `is.vector(a) && length(a) == 1 && is.na(a)` should work.

Comment: @r2evans seems to work, but I have no idea why that would achieve a sane behavior

Comment: A `data.frame` is not a vector, so the first one ensures that (might also do `!is.data.frame(x)`, but that might be *too* specific). Second one catches somebody passing a vector/list of length more than 1; I'm making an assumption there, perhaps you don't need that part.

Comment: Could instead check `inherits(x, c("numeric", "logical", "character")) && is.na(x)`. This will not trigger on `list`, `data.frame`, or `matrix`.

Comment: While I cannot disagree (many machinations are counter-intuitive and/or inconsistent), R has not had a massive/incompatible migration pathway like py2-to-py3 (which may not be truly *massive*, per se, but I think you understand my point). I think if there were serious efforts to write "R2" (that's a new version of the R language spec, not a play on my nickname), there would be many things completely rewritten for consistency, readability, and perhaps performance. I see no such efforts, however, and think it would be a very difficult move.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions by @r2evans certainly work but `identical()` and `is()` might be useful when you require a single logical values.

The example uses `identical` and `is` in a test of your requirements and should return `TRUE` **only** for a single `NA` or a `data.frame` and `FALSE` for all other input.

```
# test function where "|" is OK since both return single values
  test <- function(x) is(x, "data.frame") | identical(x, NA))

# test cases
a <- list(
  data.frame(1:3, 4:6), # data.frame
  data.frame(),         # empty data.frame
  NA,                   # single NA
  c(NA, NA, NA),        # vector of NAs
  c(NA, 1.23, NA),      # vector with an NA
  NULL,                 # single NULL
  list(1:3, 4:6),       # list that's almost a data.frame
  1L:3L,                # vector of integers
  LETTERS[1:5])         # vector of characters

# test
  sapply(a, test)
> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Only the first three elements return `TRUE`.